# CREATE USER fails when

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to replicate the SQL required to create a user with privileges, if I use HeidiSQL GUI interface to create a USER and set the privileges it works, then I delete the user from the User manager in HeidiSQL and copy SQL from echoed response area at the bottom of HeidiSQL:

```
CREATE USER 'simon'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Just the above, nothing more, but it fails with a dialog containing:

```
SQL Error (1396): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'simon'@'localhost'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to perform a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` before trying to create an account that was recently removed. This is the result of [a very old bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=28331) in MySQL server. By flushing the privileges the system will properly “forget” that `simon@localhost` existed.